# Understanding the x-ms-resource-usage in DocumentDB response header

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

While performing a simple Get operation by Id where a single document is returned (not an array with one document) I get the following x-ms-resource-usage:

`x-ms-resource-usage:documentSize:0;documentsSize:288;collectionSize=307;`

Questions:

- Why is `documentSize` 0?
- What is the unit of measure? Bytes?
- What is the difference between `documentSize` and `documentsSize`? Please note the query only returns one document.
- What is the `collectionSize`? Is that the total number of documents in the collection?
- What is the difference between `x-ms-resource-usage` and `x-ms-resource-quota`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the numbers are as follows, and all in KB:

- `documentSize`: Size of the document
- `documentsSize`: Combined size of all documents in collection
- `collectionSize`: Combined size of all documents in collection, along with overhead such as indexes

`x-ms-resource-usage` is about consumed resources within the collection, while `x-ms-resource-quota` is going to give you your limits. So with quota, you'll see `documentsSize` and `collectionSize` both set to something like 10485760, which is 10GB (10,485,760 MB).

Comment: I don't think these are right. In my tests documentSize is *almost* a direct conversion to documentsSize, if it were a Byte to Kilobyte conversion. For example, for one document I have 21107 in documentSize, and 21483559 in documentsSize. Something similar also happens to other documents, and for every getCurrentResourceQuotaUsage (in the same collection) I get totally different values.

Answer (score 0):

documentSize and documentsSize are the same value - first one in MB and the second one in kB. Apparently, documentSize is being deprecated.

collectionSize = documentsSize+metadata (in kB)