# Is there a way to know using c# the available space in a collection in documentdb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to balance my workload over different collections, each one up to 10GB, and I need to know if there is a way to know what is the free space in a particular collection using c#, in order to automate the process.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35298151/272109) I posted a while back, which explains what is returned in the `x-ms-resource-usage` and `x-ms-resource-quota` headers you execute a request. This might give you a good idea how to accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As David Makogon mentioned in his comment, we could get resource usage info from ResourceResponse. Please refer to the following sample code using the `DocumentClient.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync` method, which returns a ResourceResponse that contains a number of usage properties.

```
var colls = await client.ReadDocumentCollectionFeedAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("database id"));

Console.WriteLine("\nReading all DocumentCollection resources for a database");

foreach (var coll in colls)
{
    ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> response = await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(coll.SelfLink);

    Console.WriteLine(coll.Id + "; " + response.CollectionSizeUsage.ToString());

    //or retrieve resource usage from response.ResponseHeaders["x-ms-resource-usage"]
}
```

Comment: @Julio, any updates? are you able to retrieve the usage properties? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others quick find it and solve similar problem.